# wideanglecamera tutorial not working with Gazebo 6.7

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to run the [wideanglecamera tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=wide_angle_camera&branch=wideanglecamera) with Gazebo 6.7.  The camera shows up under the insert menu and I can insert the sensor which then appears as a box in the GUI.  However, when I hit Ctrl-T to list the topics, there is no ImageStamped topic to choose like there is if I insert a normal camera.

There are no errors in the terminal window from which I launched Gazebo.

Any thoughts on how I can debug this?

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15893/wideanglecamera-tutorial-not-working-with-gazebo-6.7/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3069/pi-robot/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7 on 2017-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

looking at the [Changelog](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/4e250e782cf04f70d2db6ad885a59bf6186691af/Changelog.md?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), the wide angle camera feature was added in gazebo 7. The tutorial needs to be updated to reflect this. It's actually in a branch and never got merged.

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2017-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3069/pi-robot/) on 2017-04-19**:
Thanks!  I'll install Gazebo 7 and give it a try.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3069/pi-robot/) on 2017-04-20**:
Just confirming that the wide angle camera works in Gazebo 7.

**Comment by [doctorroboto](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1589/doctorroboto/) on 2017-08-30**:
It also doesn't appear that the 'wideanglecamera' type is listed in the SDF options.